# Why does my regex not work inside string.match()?

Tags: javascript, regex, text-parsing

I think that this regex should work:

```
/(?s)\<strong\>.+\<\/strong\>/
```

It validates and matches everything between `<strong>` tags at regex101.com.

However, it doesn't match anything when I use it in the regex `match()` method.

```js
var string = "text text <strong>some text</strong> text text";

var re = /(?s)\<strong\>.+\<\/strong\>/;

alert(string.match(re));
```

This should alert the `<strong>` tags and everything in between.  However, it doesn't work at all.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading `(?s)` is an invalid group in a JavaScript regex. The browser console surely produced an error when you tried that.

You don't need to escape `<` or `>`, so this works:

```
var re = /<strong>.+<\/strong>/;
```

Note that if you have several `<strong>` elements in a run of text, your regular expression will match everything from the first `<strong>` to the last `</strong>`, because the `+` quantifier is *greedy*. You can change that:

```
var re = /<strong>.+?<\/strong>/;
```

Comment: When is `(?s)` allowed in a RegExp?  RegExp101.com explains that it is an inline modifier . . .

Comment: @Godisgood it's valid in some environments, but JavaScript does not support the complete PCRE syntax. In that regex101 tool you used, you can select "JavaScript" on the upper left and then it will show you that it's an error too.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sometimes, maybe.

Comment: for that case you must use `[\S\s]+?` instead of `.+?`

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, and I think `[^]` also will match any character, though it doesn't work in old versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript won't support `(?s)` DOTALL modifier. So use `[\S\s]` instead of `.` in your regex.

```
<strong>[\s\S]+<\/strong>  // greedy match
```

For non-greedy match, you need to add the quantifier `?` next to the `+` symbol.

```
<strong>[\s\S]+?<\/strong>
```

`[\s\S]+` matches also the newline characters but `.+` won't match line breaks.

```
> var string = "text text <strong>some text</strong> text text";
undefined
> var re = /<strong>[\s\S]+?<\/strong>/;
undefined
> console.log()

undefined
> console.log(string.match(re));
[ '<strong>some text</strong>',
  index: 10,
  input: 'text text <strong>some text</strong> text text' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try it in browser js console(Ctrl + Shift +K in firefox) you will get error 
SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

It works without (?s) part, you don't need it

```
var string = "text text <strong>some text</strong> text text";

var re = /\<strong\>.+\<\/strong\>/;

alert(string.match(re));
```